# Using Google OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been following this guide perfectly https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts in an attempt to get any little bit of information back from google, yet I keep getting a `403 Insufficient Permission`.

I have created a service account, and it has given me a little json file with a  private key, project ID, a client email and client ID, and lots of other nifty stuff that I cannot share here on stack overflow.

I then delegated domain wide authority to the service account to speciifc API scopes. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly` I did this through Google Apps domain's admin console.

I then prepared to make an authorized api call with this little bit of php.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$user_to_impersonate = 'my_real_email@companyname.com';


putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/alexfallenstedt/Desktop/Code/sticky-dash/service-account.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);

$sqladmin = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin($client);
$response = $sqladmin->instances->listInstances('examinable-example-123')->getItems();
echo json_encode($response) . '\n';

?>
```

I run this php file in console, and I keep getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

I am lost. My whole team is lost. We've gone through this multiple times. How can we set up server to server communication to fetch our google analytics reporting api data?

Comment: I don't see any authentication tokens. Did you acquired your access and refresh tokens? They are sent to you after the user's consent.

Comment: @Arbels The application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. The step that this 2-legged o-auth example is failing is when my application prepares to make authorized API call. I am using the service account's credentials to request an access token from the OAuth 2.0 auth server, but I keep getting permission errors.

The credentials are stored in an environment variable `putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS...');`, which are used in `$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();`.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the most common [server-side app](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). Are you sure you're qualified to use the [app default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) approach?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forgetting the beta version, and instead referred to v3 of two-legged OAuth. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php